# Send notification to specific user using FCM Dashboard

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is there any way send notification to user using his email address or UID using the Firebase Cloud Messaging Dashboard (Android app) ?

Answer (score 2):

No, for sending push notification you need fcm token. Unless you maintain a mapping of userId/email to fcm token it's not possible

Answer (score -1):

For php you can use this snipped to send notifications to the users

```
<?php

$tokens = array("yourFcmUserToken");
//you can add more to this array to send the message to multiple users, e.g. fetch an array of tokens from database

$message = array("message" => "This is message from Firebase");
$message_status = send_notification($tokens, $message);
echo "<br>".$message_status;
echo "<br>send: ".$message["message"]."<br>";

function send_notification ($tokens, $message){
    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
    $fields = array(
         'registration_ids' => $tokens,
         'data' => $message
        );

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization:key=yourGoogleApiKey',
        'Content-Type: application/json'
        );

   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);  
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
   $result = curl_exec($ch);
   if ($result === FALSE) {
       die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
   }
   curl_close($ch);
   return $result;
}

?>
```

and receive the message in the app like below

```
    public class FirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "FirebaseMessagingService";

    /**
     * Called when message is received.
     *
     * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
     */
    // [START receive_message]
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        // There are two types of messages data messages and notification messages. Data messages
        // are handled
        // here in onMessageReceived whether the app is in the foreground or background. Data
        // messages are the type
        // traditionally used with GCM. Notification messages are only received here in
        // onMessageReceived when the app
        // is in the foreground. When the app is in the background an automatically generated
        // notification is displayed.
        // When the user taps on the notification they are returned to the app. Messages
        // containing both notification
        // and data payloads are treated as notification messages. The Firebase console always
        // sends notification
        // messages. For more see: firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options
        // [END_EXCLUDE]
        
        
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        Log.d(TAG, "Data: " + remoteMessage.getData());

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());

            if (/* Check if data needs to be processed by long running job */ true) {
                // For long-running tasks (10 seconds or more) use WorkManager.
                
                //todo
                //scheduleJob();
            } else {
                // Handle message within 10 seconds
                //todo
                //handleNow();
            }

        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
    }
}
```